# pulseaudio-equalizer doesn't work on Debian 9

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, pulseaudio-equalizer

After installing pulseaudio-equalizer it doesn't seem to be bound to pulseaudio

### My `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` inspired from [here](https://www.dotpointer.ga/?section=notes&view=note&id_notes=71)

```
#include system-wise config
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa

#compressor -- for normalize audio volume
.ifexists module-ladspa-sink.so
.nofail

### BEGIN: Equalized audio configuration
### Generated from: pulseaudio-equalizer
load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_output.compressed master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo plugin=sc1_1425.so label=sc1 control=101,401,-24,3,5,9.6

load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_output.equalized master=ladspa_output.compressed plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=0.0,-2.0,-2.0,-4.0,-4.0,-2.0,4.0,6.0,7.5,7.5,7.5,7.5,4.0,2.0,0.0

load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_output.normalized master=ladspa_output.equalized plugin=fast_lookahead_limiter_1913 label=fastLookaheadLimiter control=15,0,0.8

set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo 65536
set-sink-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo 0

load-module module-equalizer-sink
load-module module-dbus-protocol

set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo

### END: Equalized audio configuration

.fail
.endif

###use the below pactl command for alsa card should be one w/o .monitor###
###  pactl list | grep -A2 'Source #' | grep 'Name: ' | cut -d" " -f2  ###
###  pacmd list-sinks | sed -n "/^.*name:/s/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/p"         ###
###  pulseaudio -k  <<< kill pulseaudio, it will restart               ###
```

### My interfaces

```
pacmd list-sources | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index'
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor>
    index: 1
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
* index: 2
        name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    index: 3
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.equalizer.monitor>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove pulseaudio-equalizer from you system and try instaling this :

https://github.com/pulseaudio-equalizer-ladspa/equalizer